# Filterable bootstrap portfolio

Tags: filter, bootstrap-4, portfolio

Hi I'm trying to create a filterable portfolio using bootstrap cards. The problem is that when I change the filter I can't see the cards. Below is my code and screen

```
<div class="row" data-aos="fade-up">
          <div class="col-lg-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <ul id="portfolio-flters">
              <li data-filter="*" class="filter-active">All</li>
              <li class="diseg" data-filter="filter-draw">Draw</li>
              <li class="textu" data-filter="filter-texture">Texture</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

<div class="card border-0 filter filter-draw">
            <div class="portfolio section-bg">
              <div class="portfolio-container" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">
                <div class="portfolio-item filter-draw">
                  <div class="portfolio-wrap">
                    <img src="assets/img/portfolio/2d/melo-cremino.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                    <div class="portfolio-info">
                      <h4></h4>
                      <div class="portfolio-links">
                        <a href="assets/img/portfolio/2d/melo-cremino.jpg" data-gall="portfolioGallery" class="venobox"><i class="bx bx-plus"></i></a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

<div class="card border-0 filter filter-texture">
            <div class="portfolio section-bg">
              <div class="portfolio-container" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">
                <div class="portfolio-item filter-texture">
                  <div class="portfolio-wrap">
                    <img src="assets/img/portfolio/2d/environment-2.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                    <div class="portfolio-info">
                      <h4></h4>
                      <div class="portfolio-links">
                        <a href="assets/img/portfolio/2d/environment-2.jpg" data-gall="portfolioGallery" class="venobox"><i class="bx bx-plus"></i></a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

My function

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#portfolio-flters li').on('click', function(){
        var filtro = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        alert(filtro);
        if( filtro == "*"){
            alert(filtro);
            $('.filter').show('1000');
        } else {
          $(".filter").not('.'+filtro).hide('3000');
          $('.filter').filter('.'+filtro).show('3000');
        }
      });

      if ($("#portfolio-flters li").removeClass("filter-active")) {
      $(this).removeClass("filter-active");
      }
      $(this).addClass("filter-active");
  });
```

When I inspect the web page the divs are visible but on the page I don't see anything.

Can someone help me?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the the bootstrap card classes -> card-img-top, card-body, card-title, card-links
inside your element which hast the class = card

Here an example:

```html
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I guess you just need to apply the missing classes on your child elements.

And if this doesn’t work, can you post what’s inside your  tag?

Comment: I only used the card class to be able to recreate a masonry effect.
Attached images.

[image1](https://ibb.co/DVzpVrH)
[image2](https://ibb.co/FKxncpG)